# MouseOut event triggered inadequately

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, mouseout

I have a HTML code like this on my page :

```
<li><img width="100" alt="3Caballeros.png" onmouseover="show_buttons();"</img></li>
```

Basically a couple buttons should show up when the user hovers the image. The *show_buttons()* method should set this up. Here it is :

```
function show_buttons(item){
var parent =$('img[alt="'+item.alt+'"]').parent();
alert(parent.prop('tagName'));    //says LI
parent.find('img').fadeIn();      //shows the other images in the LI (they are added by JavaScript)
item.onmouseover =function () {};   //removes the event listener to the image
parent.mouseout( parent, function(){
    parent.find('img[alt!="'+item.alt+'"]').fadeOut();
});
parent.mouseover( parent, function(){
    parent.find('img[alt!="'+item.alt+'"]').fadeIn();
});
```

}

The images are added with the *prepend()* method, and the result is something like :

```
 <li><img class="first_button" src="images/first.png" style="display: none;">
 <img class="second_button" src="images/second.png" style="display: none;">
 <img width="100" alt="3Caballeros.png" onmouseover="show_buttons();"</img></li>
```

So the code is almost fine : the images are shown when the cursor enters the LI and disappear when it leaves. The problem is, when the cursor hovers one of the images added dynamically in the LI the *mouseover* event is triggered, so the image disappears. These images are in the LI, so why is the event triggered?

How can I solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Could you show some more code. E.g. how exactly are those images dynamically added...

Comment: I just edited the post.

Comment: It works when I replace the fadeIn() and the fadeOut() by show() and hide()... But I still would like my question to be answered.

Comment: Hmm...I just saw this comment. Like I said in my answer, unless I know more about the set-up (elements layout, CSS-properties etc) I am shooting in the dark :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your exact set-up (no CSS etc), but the following changes should probably do the trick:

```
// Replace 'parent.mouseout(...' with:
parent.mouseleave(...

// Replace 'parent.mouseover(...' with:
parent.mouseenter(...
```

See, also, this <kbd>**[SHORT DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/fbM4P/)**</kbd>.

***The (possible) cause of the problem***
Quoting <kbd>**[jQuery's docs](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)**</kbd> regarding `.mouseover()`:
*"This event type can cause many headaches due to event bubbling. For instance, when the mouse pointer moves over the Inner element in this example, a mouseover event will be sent to that, then trickle up to Outer. This can trigger our bound mouseover handler at inopportune times.*

In your case, when moving from one image to the next a mouseout event was generated on the image and then **bubbled up to the containing `li`**, causing that unexpected behaviour. Using <kbd>**[.mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)**</kbd> and <kbd>**[.mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)**</kbd> iseems to be a better alternative !